# Best practice with Nginx + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, was

I'm deploying a light game server using nginx + node.js on AWS Beanstalk, and this just came to me: is it better to deploy multi nodes behind nginx?

Let's assume I have three routers (functions) in node server application right now: FuncA, FuncB and FuncC, they are all in one node which means listening on one port, considering node.js is single process which should be very low performance.

So my question is should I deploy them as three node applications, each one listen on individual port, and let nginx to do the load balance work.
Am I right?

Thanks,
Yi

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying to Beanstalk, you already have an Nginx instance that sits out in front of each instance of your application.  It's built into Beanstalk.  And then, there is a load balancer in front of those.  No need to add anything else.

Comment: Thank you, and I know that, what I am asking is, is it good to separate functions to different node applications, or just keep them in one node application.

Comment: @YiZhu That depends entirely on what your application does, what resources it consumes, and how those resources contend with other methods that are called.  I've never had a situation where scaling meant it made sense to fire up different instances with different methods called on each.  I would say that would be a very rare situation, as it definitely complicates things.  If you could split your application in this way, chances are that it doesn't belong as one piece anyway.  Scale out your instances horizontally and let all three functions go to all, usually.